# (Why) Should I keep a pointer to the FileWrapper in the open document?

Tags: ios, macos, nsdocument, uidocument, nsfilewrapper

I have a working document based project with both iOS and macOS targets.  The document is a bundle and I have each target able to open   files from the other.  I  was looking at some online tutorials on  UIDocument (and  particularly [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/12779/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-1) one from Ray Wenderlich ) and  they are keeping a variable for  the (NS)FileWrapper in the document class.  I currently have my model create a FileWrapper lazily each time one is needed.  I am also discarding the fileWrapper when i unpack a model object in `read(from fileWrapper: FileWrapper, ofType typeName: String)` on NSDocument or `load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType typeName: String?)` on UIDocument.  Is there any good reason for keeping  the FileWrapper while the document is open, or is the approach  I've adopted just as functional? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a reference to the FileWrapper is recommended in Session 218 of WWDC2012 
See:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/218/